# Read SQL Print result with ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I want to check table existance as below code, but the result gives **null**.

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL PRINT 1 ELSE PRINT 0";
int? result = command.ExecuteScalar() as int?;

if(result.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0)
{ 
     // no table.
}
```

The SQL syntax works fine when I directly execute it in query window.

How can I read query result properly?

Comment: Using `Select` as per the answer is by far the easiest way to go.  If you _really_ want to use `print`, you can bind the [`InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select` instead of `PRINT`. PRINT does not return rows, it prints to the query window.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```